# Yii cgridview: родитель, потомок и тд

Tags: дерево, php, yii

Здравствуйте, сталкивался ли кто ни будь с тем что данные в `cgridview` нужно вывезти следующем образом

```
Каталог 1  
 -каталог 1.1  
 -каталог 1.2  
Каталог 2   
 -каталог 2.1  
 -каталог 2.2
```

т.е. в Дереве Родитель-потомки, учитывая что структура бд обычная `id`, `title`, `parent_id`

Comment: Нужно использовать именно CGridView или возможен вариант с [Nested Tree](http://www.yiiframework.com/extension/nestedtree/ ) ?